# Android Studio 3.6.2 build error - mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android-studio

Everything is up to date as of today.
All SDKs are installed and updated.
Latest Gradle.

Have just run the:
 git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/watchface

...to learn how to make Wear OS smartwatch faces with Android Studio. There were a ton of dependency errors and now this...!???

Really at my wits end with AS...such a behemoth of a nightmare...neverending errors..Please someone help me out of this misery! I've been at this ALL day!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':1-base:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':1-base:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.2-6040484/aapt2-3.6.2-6040484.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.2-6040484/aapt2-3.6.2-6040484-windows.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :1-base

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the android.support library is no longer being maintained which would explain the other errors I keep getting. So basically the code lab tutorial is completely pointless as now it's all about AndroidX. I knew there was a reason I left a career as a programmer to become a teacher. Utterly ridiculous. And the tutorial is only months old!!! Out of date already...!

FU Google.